# Prove if $p(z)\neq w$ for $|z|<1,$ then $p(z)-\dfrac{(1-e^{i\theta})}{n}zp^{\prime}(z)\neq w,$ $\forall \theta\in[0,2\pi).$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

If a polynomial $p(z)$ of degree $n$ such that $p(z)\neq w$ for $|z|<1,$ then $p(z)-\dfrac{(1-e^{i\theta})}{n}zp^{\prime}(z)\neq w,$ $\forall \theta\in[0,2\pi).$
I know this can be proved by using Laguerre's theorem concerning the polar derivative of a polynomial. I am looking for alternative solution.

Alternative solutions are welcome.